# screencapture command on mac fails silently when sshed in

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, screenshot

I'm trying to tinker with a machine where I can only connect via shell. I don't have physical access and can't access VNC (maybe that's another question). I'm trying to take a screenshot right now to see what's going on, using `screencapture` over `ssh`, but it doesn't save the screenshot. No error message or anything. And there's no verbose mode for `screencapture`, so I can't diagnose it easily.

This is what happens when I try to take the screenshot:
`Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$ screencapture 0911.png`
`Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$`
(returns to shell and outputs nothing)

`Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 roger  staff    68 Sep 11 19:56 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 32 roger  staff  1088 Sep 11 19:56 ..
Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$`

---

*EDIT*: Beroe has suggested that being connected through SSH is a factor. I've edited my question to reflect the fact that I am doing this all over SSH. Unfortunately, `screencapture` still fails silently even when I follow the instructions given in the man page:

`Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$ ps -axww | grep loginwindo[w]
   82 ??         0:05.10 /System/Library/CoreServices/loginwindow.app/Contents/MacOS/loginwindow console
Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$ sudo launchctl bsexec 82 screencapture 0915.png
Rogers-iMac:screenshots roger$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   2 roger  staff    68 Sep 11 19:56 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 32 roger  staff  1088 Sep 15 10:17 ..`

Comment: Can you use the AppleScript solution? That worked for me. Wouldn't be hard to move the file it generates to a new directory.

Answer (score 2):

You are ssh'd to the machine and trying to get a picture of the screen?

Using AppleScript, it won't let you generate the file name, but you can at least save a screenshot to your `Desktop` folder:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "#" using command down'
```

---

The "right way" using `screencapture` doesn't work when you are remote... There is this caveat in the documentation:

> SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
>    To capture screen content while logged in via ssh, you must launch `screencapture` 
>    in the same mach bootstrap hierarchy as loginwindow:
>
> ```
>  PID=pid of loginwindow
>  sudo launchctl bsexec $PID screencapture [options]
> ```

LATER: I have tried to get this to work remotely... You can get the PID of login window looking at the first number in this output:

```
ps -axww | grep loginwindo[w]
```

However the command still does not seem to take...

Comment: Even if you're still trying to troubleshoot a solution, it is helpful to know that being connected remotely makes a difference. I'm going to add that info in the title.

Comment: Using the applescript command doesn't work. Exits with no error, but nothing appears in my desktop.